# CFD simulation (with multiple for loops and matrix operations) is very slow to run. Looking to replace with faster numpy functions (or alternative)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

As mentioned above, the function below works, however its very slow. I am very interested in using faster/optimised numpy (or other) vectorized alternatives. I have not posted the entire script here due to it being too large.

My specific question is - are there suitable numpy (or other) functions that I can use to 1) reduce run time and 2) reduce code volume of this function, specifically the **for** loop?

Edit: mass, temp, U and dpdh are functions that carry out simple algebraic calculations and return constants

```
def my_system(t, y, n, hIn, min, mAlumina, cpAlumina, sa, V):
    dydt = np.zeros(3 * n) #setting up zeros array for solution (solving for [H0,Ts0,m0,H1,Ts1,m1,H2,Ts2,m2,..Hn,Tsn,mn])
# y = [h_0, Ts_0, m_0, ... h_n, Ts_n, m_n]
# y[0] = hin
# y[1] = Ts0
# y[2] = minL

i=0

## Using thermo
T = temp(y[i],P) #initial T
m = mass(y[i],P) #initial m

#initial values
dydt[i] = (min * (hIn - y[i]) + (U(hIn,P,min) * sa * (y[i + 1] - T))) / m # dH/dt (eq. 2)
dydt[i + 1] = -(U(hIn,P,min) * sa * (y[i + 1] - T)) / (mAlumina * cpAlumina) # dTs/dt from eq.3
dmdt = dydt[i] * dpdh(y[i], P) * V # dm/dt (holdup variation) eq. 4b
dydt[i + 2] = min - dmdt # mass flow out (eq.4a)

for i in range(3, 3 * n, 3): #starting at index 3, and incrementing by 3 because we are solving for 'triplets' [h,Ts,m] in each loop

    ## Using thermo
    T = temp(y[i],P)
    m = mass(y[i],P)

    # [h, TS, mdot]
    dydt[i] = (dydt[i-1] * (y[i - 3] - y[i]) + (U(y[i-3], P, dydt[i-1]) * sa * (y[i + 1] - T))) /  m # dH/dt (eq.2), dydt[i-1] is the mass of the previous tank
    dydt[i + 1] = -(U(y[i-3], P, dydt[i-1]) * sa * (y[i + 1] - T)) / (mAlumina * cpAlumina) # dTs/dt eq. (3)
    dmdt = dydt[i] * dpdh(y[i], P) * V # Equation 4b
    dydt[i + 2] = dydt[i-1] - dmdt # Equation 4a

return dydt
```

The functions mass, temp, U, and dpdh used inside the my_system function all take numbers as input, perform some simple algebraic operation and return a number (no need to optimise these I am just providing them for further context)

```
def temp(H,P):
    # returns temperature given enthalpy (after processing function)
    T = flasher.flash(H=H, P=P, zs=zs, retry=True).T
    return T

def mass(H, P):
    # returns mass holdup in mol
    m = flasher.flash(H=H, P=P, zs=zs, retry=True).rho()*V
    return m

def dpdh(H, P):
    res = flasher.flash(H=H, P=P, zs=zs, retry=True)
    if res.phase_count == 1:
        if res.phase == 'L':
            drho_dTf = res.liquid0.drho_dT()
        else:
            drho_dTf = res.gas.drho_dT()
    else:
        drho_dTf = res.bulk._equilibrium_derivative(of='rho', wrt='T', const='P')
    dpdh = drho_dTf/res.dH_dT_P()
    return dpdh

def U(H,P,m):
    # Given T, P, m
    air = Mixture(['nitrogen', 'oxygen'], Vfgs=[0.79, 0.21], H=H, P=P)
    mu = air.mu*1000/mWAir #mol/m.s
    cp = air.Cpm #J/mol.K
    kg = air.k #W/m.K
    g0 = m/areaBed #mol/m2.s
    a = sa*n/vTotal #m^2/m^3 #QUESTIONABLE
    psi = 1
    beta = 10
    pr = (mu*cp)/kg
    re = (6*g0)/(a*mu*psi)
 hfs = ((2.19*(re**1/3)) + (0.78*(re**0.619)))*(pr**1/3)*(kg)/diameterParticle

    h = 1/((1/hfs) + ((diameterParticle/beta)/kAlumina))

    return h
```

Reference Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcvVV.png)

Comment: Please don't remove all the code from the question, it makes it impossible to understand what you were asking about and what the answer is referring to.

Comment: My apologies, I felt the question had received the answers it was going to receive

Comment: If I understand your code and explanations correctly, you started out with a PDE system, discretized it over space with an upwind scheme, and are solving the whole thing as an system of ODEs over time. This is known as the "method of lines", which should be a helpful search term. Also, from the code side, you're calling `flasher.flash()` 3 times each iteration with the same arguments from your helper functions. You should just call it once and reuse the result.

Comment: @yut23 your understanding is exactly correct. PDE system discretised over space which let us arrive at an upside scheme, and to solve the system as a system of ODEs. As you say it is called the method of lines. I see what you mean about calling the flash function more times than is required. I don't know how to change it though, But yes the temp, mass and dpdh functions are all called more times than is required. Two questions - by any chance do you know how to adjust the loop to call each function the minimum amount of times? And 2) I'm curious to know if you have a CFD background?

Comment: I ran a profiler to check which part of the total script takes the most time to run and it is these functions, so figuring out how to call them fewer times is absolutely of value. Thank you

Comment: @yut23 apologies for tagging you in this but I was hoping you would be able to explain how the flasher.flash() calls could be reduced in the for loop. Apologies!

Comment: You can just store the flasher.flash() result in a variable in the loop body, like you do inside dpdh(), and pass that to the helper functions instead of H and P. As for the second question, I'm a computational astrophysics PhD student doing multi-D simulations of reactive flows on neutron stars.

Comment: Ah I think I see. Are you saying to just have something like: res = flasher.flash(H=H, P=P, zs=zs, retry=True) at the start of the for loop, and then when required query it like T = res.T or m = res.rho()*V etc? Interesting, and Python is your main tool for simulations?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I use a C++ code for my research (it has to run on supercomputers), but Python's my go-to language for most other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For improving the speed, you can see [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), which is useable if you use NumPy a lot but not every code can be used with Numba. Apart from that, the formulation of the equation system is confusing. You are solving 3 equations and adding the result to a single `dydt` list by 3 elements each. You can simply create three lists, solve each equation and add them to their respective list. For this, you need to re-write `my_system` as:

```python
import numpy as np

def my_system(t, RHS, hIn, Ts0, minL, mAlumina, cpAlumina, sa, V):

    # get initial boundary condition values
    y1 = RHS[0]
    y2 = RHS[1]
    y3 = RHS[2]

    ## Using thermo
    T = # calculate T
    m = # calculate m

    # [h, TS, mdot] solve dy1dt for h, dy2dt for TS and dy3dt for mdot
    dy1dt = # dH/dt (eq.2), y1 corresponds to initial or previous value of dy1dt
    dy2dt = # dTs/dt eq. (3), y2 corresponds to initial or previous value of dy2dt
    dmdt =  # Equation 4b
    dy3dt = # Equation 4a, y3 corresponds to initial or previous value of dy3dt


    # Left-hand side of ODE
    LHS = np.zeros([3,])

    LHS[0] = dy1dt
    LHS[1] = dy2dt
    LHS[2] = dy3dt

    return LHS
```

In this function, you can pass `RHS` as a list with initial values (`[dy1dt, dy2dt, dy3dt]`) which will be unpacked as `y1`, `y2`, and `y3` respectively and use them for respective differential equations. The solved equations (next values) will be saved to `dy1dt`, `dy2dt`, and `dy3dt` which will be returned as a list `LHS`.

Now you can solve this using `scipy.integrate.odeint`. Therefore, you can leave the for loop structure and solve the equations by using this method as follows:

```python
hIn = #some val 
Ts0 = #some val 
minL = #some val
mAlumina = #some vaL
cpAlumina = #some val
sa = #some val
V = #some val
P = #some val

## Using thermo
T = temp(hIn,P) #initial T
m = mass(hIn,P) #initial m

#initial values
y01 = # calculate dH/dt (eq. 2)
y02 = # calculate dTs/dt from eq.3
dmdt = # calculate dm/dt (holdup variation) eq. 4b
y03 = # calculatemass flow out (eq.4a)

n = # time till where you want to solve the equation system
y0 = [y01, y02, y03]
step_size = 1
t = np.linspace(0, n, int(n/step_size)) # use that start time to which initial values corresponds
res = odeint(my_sytem, y0, t, args=(hIn, Ts0, minL, mAlumina, cpAlumina, sa, V,), tfirst=True)

print(res[:,0]) # print results for dH/dt
print(res[:,1]) # print results for dTs/dt
print(res[:,2]) # print results for Equation 4a
```

Here, I have passed all the initial values as `y0` and chosen a step size of `1` which you can change as per your need.

Comment: This is massively helpful. You went ahead and did what I wanted to do in the rest of the script (solve the system with an ODE solver). Your code is way more efficient than mine though. I do have questions - why odeint over solve_ivp? Does your version of my_system really operate the same as mine, without the for loop to set up the equations for each position? Here is a pastern of my code (below), where I use solve_ivp. I would highly appreciate a short discussion with you on optimising my version of the code. My hope is that by optimising (and reducing code volume), I'll find the error in it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vsEr6BRN (it is also semi-mindblowing to me that there exists people on stack that can immediate help with a problem I've been stuck on for days)

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you can also do the same with `solve_ivp`. Yes, my version of the code works the same (you just need to model your equations correctly for `dy1dt`, `dy2dt`, and `dy3dt`). Even if you are using `solve_ivp`, I don't understand the for loop in your code. `solve_ivp` does this (solve the ODE at provided time interval) exactly. That's why I also removed that part (for-loop part) from my proposed code.

Comment: My code differs from yours in the fact that it solves all three variables separately, whereas you are doing that in one variable and printing the results after every 3 points in the same list. It is far more clear and easy to treat each variable and its derivative as a separate variable.

Comment: I don't understand solve_ivp well then, but I thought the for loop allowed me to set up the 3 equations for each position (its an upwind scheme so position j is dependent on j-1 etc). I understand that solve_ivp will iterate through time, however I don't see how it also iterates through position i.e. how does it solve for each derivative value, at each position? Or does it do this now that the for loop is gone?

Comment: I think I follow (your second comment). You're right my method is very convoluted/unnatural. Would it be ok with you if I update my code in the pastebin file to your method and ask you to take a look?

Comment: `solve_ivp` solves each derivative value w.r.t. the rate equations that you pass in `my_system`. There are methods that do exactly what that for-loop does inside (of course it has higher-order and efficiently implemented methods like you are using Randau for example). The Randau algorithm is used in your case to solve the equations. So you don't need to implement a for-loop. Just provide it with the system of equations and the initial values and that's it, the rest is done by the solver. I can take a look to your updated code :)

Comment: Oh thats interesting. I see how solve_ivp/odeint solves each derivative w.r.t time, however to me it looks like it is just solving for one position currently (I'm trying to solve for all positions at all times). I'll read through your code carefully and make an attempt at this. Thank you! Should hopefully be back with an attempt this evening

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand what you mean by positions? If you mean the previous position of the derivative, then it saves the previous position in the solver history and adds the new solution to the previous one so you get an updated derivative at each time.

Comment: Going off my original code, the first commented line in my_system is # y = [h_0, Ts_0, m_0, ... h_n, Ts_n, m_n], so we are solving for h, Ts and m at all positions from 0 to n, at each time increment, like a 2D array I suppose. I see how odeint would solve for one value of each, at each time, however I don't see how it sets up the n x t array. Do you see what I mean? Actually if you take a look at that pastebin link, it shows the setup of position also, not just time!

Comment: I already saw your code, you are also passing `y0` as `np.asarray([H0, Ts0, min] * n)` which is unnecessary as you just need to provide `np.asarray([H0, Ts0, min])`, the rest is done by the solver. Remove the for loop as I suggested and remove `n`, and solve for `t` using `solve_ivp` you will get the same behaviour. You don't need to explicitly define positions as your rate equations are differentiated w.r.t. time. It automatically selects the position for you. If you want explicit positions, you can pass that using `t_eval` but you neither need the `n` nor the `for-loop` structure.

Comment: Very interesting, ok I don't see how this works yet, so I will study your code. Just to be absolutely sure we are talking about the same thing, see my post description I have added a link to an image of a plot I am looking to produce. It is a time vs temperature plot, at a number of positions. So for example, with n = 3 I would be able to produce three 'graphs' of time vs temperature (at 3 positions in the system), because we would be solving this system of differential equations at 3 points in the system. If you agree with this I will start studying your code now

Comment: What I understand from your code by looking at it at one time is that for n=3, you will get some values of `dydt`, where the temperature will be at 2nd, 5th, 8th position, and so on. In my version of the code all these values will be together in `res[:,1]`. Also, I am not sure what is `y` in your code as I don't see it defined anywhere. Also, I am not sure what your `solution.y` looks like.

Comment: Ahh, yes I see it now. I'm 99% sure your code does what mine does. Thanks for your explanation. Ok I'm going to aim to implement this now. I will hopefully have a minimal version of this code done this evening. Huge thanks for your help on this (I would still like to post the new code here for your review if this is ok with you!)

Comment: That’s fine I can check it tomorrow for sure. BTW if this helped you, you should maybe see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :).

Comment: Accepted as the answer. I'll spend time getting my head around this tonight then. Thank you!

Comment: So I worked through your code, and I think my initial thought about the code not doing the same thing my code did was correct (open to correction on that). I wrote out a high level description of the system and uploaded to imgur here: https://imgur.com/gallery/xslCyaw. I've added a short caption to both images to show my thoughts. I'll actually add these to the post description also. After scanning my writing, do you still think your code does the same thing as mine? Thank you

Comment: Images are actually too large to add to the description, so they will have to be accessed through my link in the last comment. Also my apologies for extending this discussion, I do think it can be resolved in a short discussion

Comment: Just as a last note, looking at the way my_system was originally set up, was this definitely inefficient? Outside the for loop was the initial t=0 calculation for each derivative, and then inside the for loop is the calculation of all derivatives at all positions, where n = position (not time)

Comment: Okay after seeing your writing now I understand much better. My code doesn't do exactly the same as yours. But the problem is still that in your version you always calculate initial values inside `my_system` whereas you should send them once as `y`. Maybe what you can do is that you implement it as my suggestion and then append the results of each `n` to the result list as a list comprehension. Something like `res = [solve_ivp(my_system, t, y0, args=(i, hIn, min, mAlumina, cpAlumina, sa, V), method='Radau') for i in range(n)]`. This way you have results for all `n` in a list.

Comment: Of course, for this, you must send `n` as an argument in the equation system and add it as an argument in `my_system` as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying I should calculate the derivatives for position 0 (and time zero) outside my_system? Does this make a difference though, is it not the same result? Also, apologies for the many questions. You are the first (maybe only) person I have found that can possibly solve this issue. As a side note - if you prefer I can repost a new question with the updated question

Comment: You are right. That won't be much different but the formulation of the equation system would be (IMO) better. Actually, for me it is difficult to understand right now, how and why the initial values change w.r.t. `n`. I guess you should post this as a new updated question. My apologies that I misunderstood it at the beginning. I will try to answer your next question as well if I have a better solution.

Comment: I agree with you that formulating the equation system would be better and much more natural to understand. No bother, I should have explained the system much more clearly. I can explain the system in any level of detail, however (obviously), I need help to fix my code as I'm new to this. I'll repost with more detail and link it here. Thank you for the help on this

Comment: One other question - do you know if physics stack exchange (or similar) would be more suitable for a CFD model like this?

Comment: If your question is really about programming and implementation of the model then I guess SO is the right platform. If you have questions about the modeling and physical meaning of the equations then I would prefer [Physics.se].